# What is the correct pathstring for sqlalchemy db on Debian GCP server?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, debian

I'm using Arch as my dev machine. I need the db to be stored in `/home/$USER/projectname/directory/`.

This works correctly on my dev machine but not on a Debain GCP server:

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///directory/users.sqlite', echo=True)
```

I tried this (replacing $USER with correct path string):

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///home/$USER/projectname/directory/users.sqlite', echo=True)
```

Which does not work.

This is the only thing that works, but it creates the db in the wrong directory:

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.sqlite', echo=True)
```

What is the correct pathstring for the db?

This is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1267, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 615, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/trade/db.py", line 35, in <module>
    base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5792, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3238, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3228, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3264, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2426, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1267, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 615, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: You say it does not work. Did you check the error log for possible reasons? Such as not having permission to create a file in the target location.

Comment: I did check the exception but I don't quite understand it yet.  I posted it above.

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
The file does not exist, can you create it and make sure your sqlalchemy application has enough permission to access it? Always check the error log after you update.

Comment: Ya I understand that but what I don't understand is why does this work `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.sqlite', echo=True)` but this doesn't `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///directory/users.sqlite', echo=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
```

Please make sure the target **directory exists** first and that your SQLAlchemcy
application has the permission to create files in that directory. It is probably
because the directory does not exist.

Note it's 4 slashes with an absolute path (////home), not 3:

```
sqlite:////home/$USER/projectname/directory/users.sqlite
```

Comment: The directory does exist and my application has permission to create files in that directory.

Comment: Use an absolute path this time and show us the error log if it does not succeed.

Comment: 4 slashes, not 3. I updated my answer. sqlite:////home

Comment: 4 slashes worked!!  Thank you so much.